# React-Router open route when page loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want the first Route below (path="/tasks") to open when a user opens my page. Now when a user opens my page they don't see any of the components. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/tasks" element={<AllTasks completeTask={completeTask} removeTask={removeTask} />} />
  <Route path="/upcoming" element={<UpcomingReminders completeTask={completeTask} removeTask={removeTask} />} />
  <Route path="/today" element={<TodaysReminders completeTask={completeTask} removeTask={removeTask} />} />
  <Route path="/form" element={<Form />} />
  <Route path="/missed" element={<MissedTasks removeTask={removeTask} completeTask={completeTask} />}></Route>
  <Route path="/recurring" element={<Recurring completeTask={completeTask} removeTask={removeTask} />}></Route>
  <Route path="/completed" element={<CompletedTasks removeCompletedTask={removeCompletedTask} />}></Route>
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: `<Route path="/" element={<AllTasks completeTask={completeTask} removeTask={removeTask} />} />`?

Comment: `<Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/tasks" />} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `"/tasks"` route to be a sort of "default" route then render a redirect to that specific route.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route index element={<Navigate to="/tasks" replace />} /> // redirect to default path
  <Route
    path="/tasks"
    element={<AllTasks completeTask={completeTask} removeTask={removeTask} />}
  />
  ...
</Routes>
```

Comment: This works on the browser, but I am actually making a chrome extension and it the component does not appear when I open the extension. Any idea why?

Comment: @MichaelHorvilleur Nope, not really. Can you edit your question to provide a more accurate representation of the code you are working with that has an issue? Are there any errors in the console? What debugging steps have been taken?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an array in `path` and don't forget the `exact` parameter

```
<Route path=["/", "/tasks"] exact element={<AllTasks completeTask={completeTask} removeTask={removeTask} />} />
```

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6` where the `path` prop takes *only* a string value, not an array, and there is no longer any `exact` prop.